# PHP memory usage difference on local (Windows) and VPS (Fedora)

Tags: php, linux, windows, memory-management

In my project I use my own framework, and sure I use my own logging time and memory. Now I found that my memory usage statistics different in different environments. Here I mean two environment: local Windows and production VPS Fedora.

Here is the logger view:

```
<style>
    div.lt-timer {
        opacity: 0.5; background: #FFF; color: #777; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #CCC;
        font-size: 0.85em; position: fixed; max-width: 300px; max-height: 600px; overflow: auto;
        bottom: 10px; right: 10px; padding: 5px;
    }
    div.lt-timer h4 { text-align: center; font-weight: 700; }
</style>
<div class="lt-timer">
    <h4><?php echo $timer->getName(); ?></h4>
    <?php echo nl2br(implode('', $timer->getPoints())); ?>
    <h4>Total used memory: <?php echo round(memory_get_usage() / 1024, 2); ?> KB</h4>
</div>
```

Everything is fine, except this line, which gives difference:

```
<h4>Total used memory: <?php echo round(memory_get_usage() / 1024, 2); ?> KB</h4>
```

On Windows I've got about **598** KB, but for the same request I have **2976** KB on VPS Fedora.

I've also have tested for same test.php files containing this:

```
<?php
    $a = 999;
    $b = 999;
    $c = 999;

    echo memory_get_usage();
?>
```

And that's what I got:

Local machine (Windows): **329280**
Production machine (Fedora): **633392**

Does eAccelerator or xCache could affect this statistics? Or where I'm wrong?

Comment: There are a **ton** of variables here, the least of which are your code.

Comment: Two entirely different systems exhibit different memory usage patterns. No real surprise there...

Comment: 6 times more?.. That's really surprising...

Comment: And there more... Unix system which is built for server-running and Windows 7 64-bit system on gaming laptop m17x R3... I don't get it. Where is the logic? Server system do need have improved memory management system... or what?

Comment: Most if it seems to be the PHP core itself, and any module or extension, the exact build of those modules, etc. will influence it (and yes, caching modules usually dig deep, so often increase base-memory footprint). However: where is the problem? Are you encountering memory-issues?

Comment: No, there is no problem for now, but I just want to know the reasons... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 5.2.x, the [memory_get_usage()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) function has a parameter.

```
 int memory_get_usage  ([ bool $real_usage = false  ] )
```

According to php.net, **$real_usage** is:

> Set this to TRUE to get the real size of memory allocated from system. If not set or FALSE only the memory used by emalloc() is reported.

Additionally [some sources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php#87092) say PHP needs to be loaded as a CGI in Apache to correctly get memory usage by process id using getmypid().

Comment: That gives the same, but not so much difference: `524288` / `786432`

Answer (score 1):

php runs as part as apache in linux, and standalone in windows. maybe that could mean the memory difference?